# Magento - Set product visibility on observer at store level before product save

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have 2 websites, each of which has 2 stores.

When I create a product from a store(say, Store 1) of a website(say, Website 1), and if I set the websites for this product as Website 1 and Website 2, the product's visibility is set as `catalog, Search` only for the store from which I created it(Store 1). As for the other stores, the visibility is set to `Not Visible Individually`.

I have an observer for `catalog_product_save_before`, in which I want to set this visibility at store level.

Tried this code:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
                    array($productId),
                    array('visibility'=>4),
                    1
                );
```

and it works. But for this, I need to get the productId, which I wont get since the product is not yet saved in my observer function.

How do I set this product visibility for a particular store(say Store 3 of Website 2) to `catalog, Search` in the `catalog_product_save_before` observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it.

The observer function:

```
public function before_product_save($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product->setStoreId(1)->setData('visibility', 4);
}
```

where, the store id is 1 and the visibility attribute value 4 refers to `Catalog, Search`.